# react: focus out detect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onfocus

How to detect an event FocusOut?

There are events for FocusIn: `onFocusCapture`, `onFocus`

But I didn't find the event for FocusOut

```
render() {
    return (
        <input onFocusCapture = {this.handleFocusIn} onUNKNOWN = {this.handleFocusOut} />
    );
}
```

Comment: Here is a event called: onfocusout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp

Comment: `onBlur` is what you want on an input, anyway, just use that. [a note from the master himself](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6410#issuecomment-671499208)

Comment: @Stephen, `onfocusout` in react not working